# Why select-string doesnot receive from pipelining

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to parse out the patterns from a file and search the files for those strings then group them. Here is the code and the error I am getting

```
PS D:\Shared_With_Pai\Testing> Get-Content C:\\events.txt | Select-String -pattern $_  * |Select-Object LineNumber,FileName|Format-Table -GroupBy FileName
Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null.
At line:1 char:52
+ Get-Content C:\\events.txt | Select-String -pattern <<<<  $_  * |Select-Object LineNumber,FileName|Format-Table -GroupBy FileName
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStrin
gCommand
```

Can anybody say where I am making the mistake?

**EDIT:**
The contents of events.txt is something like

```
8,coilevent,networkchange
8,coilevent,malfunction
8,coilevent,conflictwithpc
```

I am searching some csv files for these lines.

Comment: please provide a sample of events.txt . Which files are you trying to search for the patterns ?

Comment: I can't actually figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Downvoter Be reasonable. What is the reason behind the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

The current object variable `$_` isn't populated with objects from the pipeline if you use it that way. As [@Kayasax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22606549/1630171) suggested, you need to put the statement in a loop if you want it to work like that:

```
Get-Content C:\events.txt | % { Select-String -Pattern $_ * } | ...
```

However, there's no need to read the input from a pipeline in the first place. `-Pattern` accepts a string array, so you can simply read the file with the patterns in a subexpression:

```
Select-String -Pattern (Get-Content 'C:\events.txt') * | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you're searching for sometking like (note that the select-string alias `sls` works only on powershell V3 )
:

```
$patterns=gc c:\temp\events.txt 
ls c:\temp\*.csv |%{
     sls -Pattern $patterns $_ |Select-Object LineNumber,FileName|Format-Table -GroupBy FileName
}
```

Comment: I am trying to make it in single line

Answer (score 0):

Select-String is expecting a regular expression argument for a pattern. This:

```
 Get-Content C:\\events.txt | Select-String -pattern $_  *
```

Is getting the content of the file, and using it as both the pipeline data and the match argument - Each line is being matched to itself.  This makes no sense.

Then the trailing * after is going to be read as an argument to a positional parameter.

Read the help on select-string, and see

```
get-help about_regular_expressions
```

After considering @Ansgar's comments, you might be able to use this:

```
gci | sls -Pattern (gc c:\temp\events.txt) -SimpleMatch
```

The -Pattern parameter will not take pipeline input, but it will take an array of pattern arguments, and will return a match on any pattern in the array, so you don't need to use foreach-object to iterate through that array.

Comment: You can force `Select-String` to do simple matches instead of regexp matches by adding the parameter `-SimpleMatch`.

Comment: @Ansgar - that's true, but adding a -SimpleMatch switch won't fix what's wrong with this.  It will still be nonsense.

Comment: True, but I think what he's actually trying to achieve is to read the patterns from `C:\events.txt` and match them against all files in the current working directory (hence the `*` wildcard argument).

Comment: In that case you'd want -Wildcard instead of -SimpleMatch and a pattern argument of "$_ *".  That still leaves it without a filespec to have anything to match it to tho.

Comment: I meant it like this: `Select-String -Pattern $_ -Path *` to match the patterns read from `C:\events.txt` against all files in the current directory.

Comment: @Ansgar You got what I am trying to do.